How can I save two gt/gtsummary objects into one pdf file by gtsave()?
gtsave(tbl, "tbl.pdf") can save one table once. It's clear and neat. However, I'd like to insert two tables on the same .pdf file and in the same page.
Table 1. abc



Column A
Column B




Cell 1
Cell 2


Cell 3
Cell 4



Table 2. xyz



Column A
Column B




Cell 1
Cell 2


Cell 3
Cell 4




Try using R markdown or Quarto

@Ting Zhang Do you still need a way to do this, other than Daniel's suggestion?

@seehorse Yes, although I used other way to save the file, I would like to know whether it's possible to save files by gtsave().
